# Why do spring framework reference doc missing context-support in their diagram

Tags: spring, spring-4, spring-cache

The Diagram [2.1. Overview of the Spring Framework] in [Spring Framework reference 4.1.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) which is updated since last doc but it is missing spring-context-support from it. In the diagram they mentioned context ,do that represents spring-context-support as well, but actually that is totally separate. Although as per doc it states its one of the core container but I was curious if it was just a mistake of theirs Or they did it internationally.

Comment: The diagram only shows the logical seperate modules not the jars they are packaged in. There are more jars then modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Mark said already, the diagram is a logical representation of the different components. Some translates to more that one physical module.

`spring-context` and `spring-context-support` are actually "tied". The reason for the separation is that `spring-context-support` integrates with a bunch of third party libraries while `spring-context` provides the core infrastructure.

For caching (since you seem to refer to that), the basic cache infrastructure is in `spring-context` while `sprig-context-support` provides the various integration (ehcache, guava, JSR-107, etc).